# change event function in *ngfor for checkbox

Tags: angular

I am working on the project that use **Angular 2**.

In on of the situation is I have to create a checkbox from the array, So I do as follows:

```
<span *ngFor="let key of keysArray; let i = index;" >
    <input type="checkbox" checked  [value]="key"> {{key}}
  </span>
```

Now I want change/click event for every checkbox, So I do added (change) event like follow:

```
<span *ngFor="let key of keysArray; let i = index;" >
    <input type="checkbox" checked (change)="checkChange($event.checked)"  [value]="key"> {{key}}
  </span>
```

Function in component:

```
checkChange(event){
      alert(event)
    }
```

But when I run the code it showing error:

```
self.parentView.context.checkChange is not a function
```

Comment: Does the component have a `checkChange` method? Can you please add the code that shows how it looks like?

Comment: Are you sure the `$event` does have a `checked` property?

Comment: Yes there is a checkChange method in component please check @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$event.target.checked`

```
<input type="checkbox" checked (change)="checkChange($event.target.checked)"
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean exactly? Do you get exactly the same error message?

Comment: What about `<input type="checkbox" checked #cb (change)="checkChange(cb.checked)" `?

Comment: Works fine in https://plnkr.co/edit/UE8t5jOQ8vhkxQ08OrqZ?p=preview when the function exists. Otherwise I get the same error as you.

Comment: thanks @GünterZöchbauer, Actually the problem is I am writing function in other component :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `checkChange` method inside the component which the template belongs to.

The error `self.parentView.context.checkChange is not a function` means there's no function called `checkChange` inside your component.